# TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined using Angular

Tags: angularjs

[I'm following this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/) When I try to post a comment on a post I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined` error in my console.

the mainCtrl,

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts',
  function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { alert("Field can't left blank"); return; }

    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      upvotes: 0,
      comments: [
        {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
        {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
      ]
    });
  };
  }
])
```

and the postCtrl,

```
.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts',
  function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

    $scope.addComment = function(){
      if($scope.body === '') { return; }
      $scope.post.comments.push({
        body: $scope.body,
        author: 'user',
        upvotes: 0
      });
      $scope.body = '';
    };

  }
])
```

Both controllers are in `mainCtrl.js`.

And here are my home.html and post.html partials which are being included through router-ui.

```
%script{:id => "/home.html", :type => "text/ng-template"}
  %h1
    Flappernews

  %a{:href => "#/posts/{{$index}}"} Comments

%script{:id => "/posts.html", :type => "text/ng-template"}
  %h2
    Below here should be comments
  %span
    {{ post.comments }}
  %div{"ng-repeat" => "comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'"}
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    %span{:style => "font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;"}
      {{comment.body}}

  %form{"ng-submit" => "addComment()"}
    %h3 Add a new comment
    .form-group
      %input.form-control{"ng-model" => "body", :placeholder => "Comment", :type => "text"}
    %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"} Post
```

When I visit the homepage I get redirected to `localhost:3000/#/home` I can then enter a title and post it. When I click on the `comments` link I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/#/posts/` and when I try to post a comment I get the

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined` `at Scope.$scope.addComment` error.

Comment: In the `mainCtrl` you have `$scope.posts.` and in the `mainCtrl` you have `$scope.post.` Could you try to rename `$scope.post.` to `$scope.posts.` and see if that works?

Comment: See what is returned by posts.posts[$stateParams.id]; - add console.log($scope.post); to have a quick look.

Comment: Chaing `$scope.post` tot `$scope.posts` didn't change anything. And I've added `console.log($scope.post` just beneath the `$scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];` line and I'm getting a `undefined` output in the console.

Comment: So is $stateParams.id returning the correct id?

Comment: @Will it doesn't. When I click on the `comments` link then console outputs a `undefined`. When I visit the homepage it outputs a empty `[]`

Comment: @Peter I can't see how you're setting the id on $stateparams but this is where you need to look.

Comment: @Will I'm following this tutorial https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ and it's on the `Getting the Right Post` section. `.state('posts', {
  url: '/posts/{id}',
  templateUrl: '/posts.html',
  controller: 'PostsCtrl'
});`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma I can't get to that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined two separate controllers, don't need to do that. If you look at that tutorial again you will see that addPost and addComment functions are inside single controller like this

```
   .controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){

    // Fetch post object from state parameter.
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

    // Add Post.
    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
      upvotes: 0,
      comments: [
        {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
        {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
      ]
    });

    // Add comment.
    $scope.addComment = function(){
      if($scope.body === '') { return; }
      $scope.post.comments.push({
        body: $scope.body,
        author: 'user',
        upvotes: 0
      });
      $scope.body = '';
    };

    }]);
```

add post and comment works on single Post object where comments property is pre defined.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is reference link issue.  $scope.posts = posts.posts; only should be used to access the posts object. CURD operation should be performed on service directly.

$scope.posts would get automatically changed because there is a reference link between $scope.posts and posts.

Please make below change. Hope it should work.

```
    $scope.addPost = function () {
      if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
          alert("Field can't left blank");
          return;
      }

      posts.posts.push({
          title: $scope.title,
          upvotes: 0,
          comments: [{
              author: 'Joe',
              body: 'Cool post!',
              upvotes: 0
          }, {
              author: 'Bob',
              body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!',
              upvotes: 0
          }]
      });
  };
```

now you are able to share data between different controllers. Same should be done while adding comment.

Important part :

you can not get post like posts.posts[$stateParams.id]; This will match the index of array and return the object.

```
angular.forEach(posts.posts, function (post) {
    if (post.id === parseInt($stateParams.id)) {
        $scope.post = post;
        return;
    }

})
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: In the end the problem was the link to the comment pages. It was in the wrong section of the page. Fixed now. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'mainCrtl', you are not saving/adding new post data to your 'posts' object but added to '$scope.posts' so its reflecting in your page with comment link (let's say your newly created post id is 'x' ).

And when you are clicking on comments link, and trying to check the data which is not added before to your 'posts' object ie.., posts[x] is undefined (you have not added id 'x' data in maincrtl).

Hope I have Answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot debug the code so I'll try to list all possible reasons and you can confirm which is true for your case

1. Make sure the new post is pushed to the `posts` service correctly.

Place a breakpoint after the `$scope.posts.push` and log `posts.posts` to make sure the new object is added to the array

2. Make sure the `PostsCtrl` has the same `posts.posts` array with the new post added.
3. Make sure `$stateParams.id` is actually a valid index for the `posts.posts` array

I hope this helps. If not, make a comment with the results.